# how to pass open directory in C to a function that find most recently modified file and oldest modified file in C

Tags: c

I am trying to create a C program that will take a directory name as input in main and pass that open directory to the function. I have both components working seperately but cannot figure out how to pass the open directory to the function.Also I am struggling to find the oldest file.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  DIR *d;
  struct dirent *dir;
  if(argc==2){
    char* path = argv[1];
    d = opendir(path);
    if (d) {
      while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
      }
      closedir(d);
    }
    return(0);
  }else{
      printf("Wrong number of arguments");
      return 1;
  }
  
}
void getFileCreationTime(char *path) {
    struct stat attr;
    stat(path, &attr);
    printf("Last modified time: %s", ctime(&attr.st_mtime));
}

int recent(DIR *d, char *file_name, char *dir_name)
{
    
    struct dirent *entry;
    int files = 0;

    

while( (entry=readdir(entry)) )
{
    files++;
    printf("File %3d: %s\n",files, entry->d_name);
    printf("File %3d: %i\n",files, entry->d_reclen);
    getFileCreationTime(".");
}

    closedir(entry);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: This seems very wrong: `(entry=readdir(entry))`. Aren't you getting a compiler error?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is in the recent function where you are referencing the incorrect variable (entry instead of d).  Following is a snippet of code with a revision of the variable entry.

```
int recent(DIR *d, char *file_name, char *dir_name)
{

    struct dirent *entry;
    int files = 0;



    while( (entry=readdir(d)) )     /* Revised this line to utilize "d" */
    {
        files++;
        printf("File %3d: %s\n",files, entry->d_name);
        printf("File %3d: %i\n",files, entry->d_reclen);
        getFileCreationTime(".");
    }

    closedir(d);                    /* Revised this line to utilize "d" */

    return(0);
}
```

When I ran the code with this revision, I received the following terminal output.

```
@Dev:~/C_Programs/Console/Directory/bin/Release$ ./Directory /home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Directory
main.c
bin
obj
..
.
Directory.cbp
```

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.